# Git hangs on most commands such as list config

Tags: git

When executing various commands such as git config --list it will show the list but just blinking cursor and nothing works such as q, quit, esc, anything. The same goes for other commands such as git branch to see what branch i'm on. I have to close the terminal window (happens in windows cmd, git CMD, powershell, whatever).

Any ideas what the issue could be or even how do I get it to stop so I can input further commands?

Comment: What OS or shell are you using?

Comment: Windows and using Git CMD terminal also powershell.

Comment: Does it exhibit this same behavior in both CMD and Powershell?

Comment: I saw this back when I was using Windows.... if you leave the terminal alone, it will **eventually** come back to normal.... but it can take a while. I normally had plenty of terminals open so i could just go on by using a different terminal. I never understood why it happened.

Comment: Could you try running the command `git --no-pager config --list`  ?  Does it still behave the same way?

Comment: @Jens - Why do you think it sounds like a proxy issue?  The commands in question shouldn't even be attempting to access the network...

Comment: @Jens Network latency is far from the only reason something can hang.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger The --no-pager flag worked. Problem solved. However, can I set that in config so I don't have to include it with every command?

Comment: Rather than disabling the pager globally, you might figure out why your chosen pager is doing this. (If you didn't choose a pager, you might want to choose one now.) To set some particular command as your pager, use `git config --global core.pager <chosen-pager>`, or set environment variable `GIT_PAGER` or `PAGER`. To see what pager Git is currently using, run `git var GIT_PAGER`.

Comment: @torek It is default - I never changed it. It is set to "less". Not sure what other options there would be. Suggestions?

Comment: I don't use Windows so I don't know what a good Windows pager might be. But `less` *ought* to start up practically instantly—it does for me, on my (non-Windows) systems. Related: https://superuser.com/questions/426226/less-or-more-in-windows/426229